# using heredoc in case statement for remote ssh host

Tags: bash, ssh, remote, here-document, case

I have a list of ssh commands to run on remote server, so wrote this snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


echo ''
echo "WOULD YOU LIKE TO PERFORM FILES CLEANUP: "
read choice


case $choice in
  yes|YES|y|Y )

    echo ''
    echo "Enter NAME OR IP OF REMOTE HOST: "
    read ls_host


    ssh -t ${ls_host} <<- IFF
      command 1
      command 2
      command 3
    IFF;;
  * )
    echo "YOU'VE MADE A WISE-CHOISE: SCRIPT IS SKIPPING CLEANUP";;
esac
```

below error

```
warning: here-document at line # delimited by end-of-file (wanted `IFF')
```

I tried quotes around IFF also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here-docs are collected "outside" the normal syntax, based on just the input lines. So, you need to have the here-doc separator on a line of its own, and you can't combine that with other syntax. Also, the here-doc separator could itself contain syntax elements, like that `;;`...

E.g. this should print `wat` and `hi, hello`.

```
#!/bin/sh

cat << "EOF;;"
wat
EOF;;

case x in 
 x) cat <<-EOF
        hi, hello
        EOF
    ;;
 y) false;;
esac
```

Note you need hard tabs before the second `EOF` and the `hi, hello` line, and since stackexchange changes tabs to spaces, **copypasting this directly doesn't work**. That may or may not be an argument for avoiding `<<-` and instead just shoving the here-doc data to the left edge.

---

Also `read ls_host; ssh -t ${ls_host}` would allow the user to enter options to `ssh` when entering the hostname, which may or may not be what you want. Might want to use `"${ls_host}"` there, too.